# write a shell script to Display any string at given x, y position and Display current terminal number in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

How can I do these two programs in Unix/Linux shellscript

1. Display your name at given x, y position
2. Display your terminal number

Comment: See [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html), and do a `man tty`.

Answer (score 1):

2D cursor control is a platform-specific feature, but [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are often supported. This ought to work:

```sh
echo -e "\033[20;10HHello World" # prints "Hello World" at x=20, y=10
```

In case you're wondering, `\033` corresponds to an escape character (ASCII 27) when using the `-e` flag with `echo`.

Your username should be in the `$USER` environment variable:

```sh
echo $USER
```

And if by "terminal number" you're referring to the tty terminal identifier for your current shell, that's available from the command line if you type in `who am i`. This will also print your user name and login date/time, but you can extract just the terminal info with `awk`:

```sh
TTY=`who am i | awk '{ print $2 }'`
echo $TTY
```

So you can put this all together to print your username and tty identifier [in bold text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters) at the top left of your console window as follows:

```
TTY=`who am i | awk '{ print $2 }'` ; echo -e "\033[1m\033[1;1H$USER ($TTY)\033[0m"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple C program to move the cursor:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<curses.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int x;
  int y;

  if(argc < 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;

  x = atoi(argv[1]);
  y = atoi(argv[2]);

  move(x, y);
}
```

This program uses the `curses` library to move the cursor to a given location. As far as your second question, I do not know what you mean by "Terminal Number". Please edit your answer to clarify...

Comment: thanks for your response but I want to do this program in shell script

Comment: I know. I'm simply suggesting you compile this and move it into `/usr/bin`. Then, you can use it freely in any shell script you want by simply putting the name of the executable you named it (e.g. `move-cursor`) in your shell script